# LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working with an old code C++ that used to compile in older version of Visual Studio C++. I'm trying to make it compile in visual studio 2022. Proj1 project links to myLib.lib. I have code for both Proj1 and myLib. They're in the same Solution.

Upon building Proj1 I get this error:

LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in Proj1.obj
at column Project, it says:
Proj1
at column File and Line, it says:
C:\code\myLib.lib(myInterface.obj)  1

Note that myInterface.cpp and myInterface.h are in myLib project

I already did these

1. retargeted myLib project, and Proj1 project to Windows SDK Version : 10 (latest installed version).
2. at both myLib project and Proj1 I set project>Configuration Properties>General> Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2022 (v143)
3. rebuilt myLib project (I could see resulting myLib.lib), and rebuilt Proj1 - then got the error I mentioned.

a) What can I do to get rid off this compilation error?

b) Why does it still expect _MSC_VER 1900 (= Visual studio 2015)  when I already changed the platform toolset on both projects?

c) Why does it still see the myLib.lib having _MSC_VER 1900 when I already changed the Platform Toolset to v143 and built myLib.lib?

Comment: Search the source code for version defines, you might be overriding the project default somewhere like in the stdafx.h

Comment: Is your problem solved? Have you tried building from a new project?